# search for an enum in a structure in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, enums, find

I have an `enum`, a structure with this `enum` as a member and a vector of these structures as such:

```
enum TickerType { tt1, tt2, tt3 };
struct Ticker {
  std::string name;
  TickerType type;
};
std::vector<Ticker> vect;
```

I want to search for an element in `vect` which is of type `tt1`. For which I declared

```
struct find_ticker
{
  const TickerType type;
  find_ticker(TickerType type) : type(type) {};
  bool operator () ( const Ticker& ticker ) const
  {
    return ticker.type == type;
  }
};
```

and looked with:

```
 if ( std::find ( vect.begin(), vect.end(), find_ticker ( tt1 ) ) != tickers.end() )
```

But I get

> ```
> error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Dfp::Ticker’ and
>  ‘const {anonymous}::find_ticker’) ||   { return *__it == _M_value; }
> ```

*Dfp is the global namespace of the application and find_ticker is defined in an anoymous namespace in the implementation file where I need it

Comment: compare vect to tickers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function is the wrong function to call if you want to find using a predicate. `std::find` is for finding based on a value, so you are trying to find a value in the vector that is equal to the `find_ticker` object.

You should use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead.

Comment: or you could define global `bool operator==(const Ticker& lhs, const Ticker& rhs)` and use the `find` function (but perhaps that comparison would be different than just `enum` compare)